# Multiple docker apps running nginx at multiple different subpaths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-location

I'm attempting to run several Docker apps in a GKE instance, with a load balancer setup exposing them. Each app comprises a simple node.js app with nginx to serve the site; a simple nginx config exposes the apps with a location block responding to `/`. This works well locally when developing since I can run each pod on a separate port, and access them simply at 127.0.0.1:8080 or similar.

The problem I'm encountering is that when using the GCP load balancer, whilst I can easily route traffic to the Kubernetes services such that https://example.com/ maps to my `foo` service/pod and https://example.com/bar goes to my `bar` service, the `bar` pod responds with a 404 since the path, `/bar` doesn't match the path specified in the location block.

The number of these pods will scale a lot so I do not wish to manually know ahead of time what path each pod will be under, nor do I wish to embody this in my git repo.

Is there a way I can dynamically define the path the location block matches, for example via an environment variable, such that I could define it as part of the Helm charts I use to deploy these services? Alternatively is it possible to match all paths? Is that a viable solution, or just asking for problems?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **ingress**. It will allow you to map different paths to different backend `Services`. It is very well explained both in [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) as well as in the [official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Typical ingress object definition may look as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: my-products
    servicePort: 60001
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-products
          servicePort: 60000
      - path: /discounted
        backend:
          serviceName: my-discounted-products
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /special
        backend:
          serviceName: special-offers
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /news
        backend:
          serviceName: news
          servicePort: 80
```

When you apply your ingress definition on **GKE**, **load balancer** is created automatically. Note that all `Services` may use same, standard http port and you don't have to use any custom ports.

You may want to specify [a default backend](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#default_backend), present in the above example (`backend` section right under `spec`), but it's optional. It will ensure that:

> Any requests that don't match the paths in the rules field are sent to
> the Service and port specified in the backend field. For example, in
> the following Ingress, any requests that don't match / or /discounted
> are sent to a Service named my-products on port 60001.

The only problem that you may encounter when using default **ingress controller** available on **GKE** is that for the time being **it doesn't support rewrites**.

If your nginx pods expose app content only on `"/"` path, no support for rewrites shouldn't be a limitation at all and as far as I understand, this applies in your case:

> Each app comprises a simple node.js app with nginx to serve the site;
> a simple nginx config exposes the apps with a location block
> responding to /

However if you decide at some point that you need mentioned rewrites because e.g. one of your apps isn't exposed under `/` but rather `/bar` within the `Pod` you may decide to deploy [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke) which can be also done pretty easily on **GKE**.

So you will only need it in the following scenario: *user accesses the ingress IP followed by `/foo`* -> *request is not only redirected to the specific backend `Service` that exposes your **nginx** `Pod`, but also the original path (`/foo`) needs to be rewritten to the new path (`/bar`) under which the application is exposed within the `Pod`*

## UPDATE:

> Thank you for your reply. The above ingress configuration is very
> similar to what I've already configured forwarding /foo and /bar to
> different pods. The issue is that the path gets forwarded, and (after
> doing some more research on the issue) I believe I need to rewrite the
> URL that's sent to the pod, since the location / { ... } block in my
> nginx config won't match against the received path of /foo or /bar. –
> aodj Aug 14 at 9:17

Well, you're right. The original access path e.g. `/foo` indeed gets forwarded to the target `Pod`. So choosing `/foo` path apart from leading you to the respective `backend` defined in the **ingress resource** implicates that the target **nginx server** running in a `Pod` must serve its content also under `/foo` path.

I verified it with **GKE ingress** and can confirm by checking `Pod` logs that an http request sent to the **nginx** `Pod` thorough the `/foo` path, indeed comes to the `Pod` as request for `/usr/share/nginx/html/foo` while it serves its content under `/`, not /foo from `/usr/share/nginx/html`. So requesting for something that don't exist on the target server leads inevitably to `404 Error`.

As I mentioned before, default ingress controller available on **GKE** doesn't support rewrites so if you want to use it for some reason, reconfiguring your target **nginx servers** seems the only solution to make it work.

Fortunatelly we have another option which is **nginx ingress controller**. It supports rewrites so it can easily solve our problem. We can deploy it on our **GKE cluster** by running two following commands:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Yes, it's really that simple! You can take a closer look at the installation process in [official docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke).

Then we can apply the following `ingress` resource definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-deployment-1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /foo(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-deployment-2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /bar(/|$)(.*)
```

Note that we used `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation to select our newly deployed **nginx-ingress controller** to handle this **ingress resource** rather than the default **GKE-ingress controller**.

Rewrites that were used will make sure that the original access path gets rewritten before reaching the target **nginx `Pod`**. So it's perfectly fine that both sets of `Pods` exposed by `nginx-deployment-1` and `nginx-deployment-2` `Services` serve their contents under `"/"`.

If you want to quickly check how it works on your own, you can use the following `Deployments`:

**nginx-deployment-1.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-1
  labels:
    app: nginx-1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-1
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myservice
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        command: ['sh', '-c', "echo DEPLOYMENT-1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      volumes:
      - name: cache-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

**nginx-deployment-2.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-2
  labels:
    app: nginx-2
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-2
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myservice
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        command: ['sh', '-c', "echo DEPLOYMENT-2 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: cache-volume
      volumes:
      - name: cache-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

And expose them via `Services` by running:

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment-1 --type NodePort --target-port 80 --port 80
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment-2 --type NodePort --target-port 80 --port 80
```

You may even omit `--type NodePort` as **nginx-ingress** controller accepts also `ClusterIP` `Services`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The above ingress configuration is very similar to what I've already configured forwarding /foo and /bar to different pods. The issue is that the path gets forwarded, and (after doing some more research on the issue) I believe I need to rewrite the URL that's sent to the pod, since the `location / { ... }` block in my nginx config won't match against the received path of `/foo` or `/bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, SO doesn't inform me on edits!